# Querying nonexistant field in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nosql

I have an array field called `tags` in almost every document in a collection. There are a few docs that don't have that field.

If I run `db.posts.find({ "some_tag": { $in: tags } });` I'd expect MongoDB to return only the posts that do have "some_tag" in their `tag` field, and exclude the ones that don't even have the field, but I'm actually getting this error: `JavaScript execution failed: ReferenceError: miembros is not defined`

Why is that? Can I query my collection this way if some documents don't have that field?

EDIT: Problem fixed. See first comment.

Comment: Are you sure that the javascript error is related to MongoDB and not your code? MongoDB will do no javascript evaluation here

Comment: Ah, indeed. I swapped the arguments. That should be ```field: { $in: [values]}```, and not ```value: { $in: field}```. Anyways, IMHO the way I wrote the query is more logical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd expect MongoDB to return only the posts that do have "some_tag" in their tag

That's what it does, if you query it correctly:

```
> db.tags.insert({"name" : "john", "tags" : ["tag", "boo"]});
> db.tags.insert({"name" : "mike" });
> db.tags.find({"tags" : "boo" });
{ "_id" : ObjectId("525e53a5e90cc5362ea98842"), 
  "name" : "john", "tags" : [  "tag",  "boo" ] }
```

or

```
> db.tags.find({"tags" : {$in : [ "boo"] } });
{ "_id" : ObjectId("525e53a5e90cc5362ea98842"), 
  "name" : "john", "tags" : [  "tag",  "boo" ] }
```

The problem is that you inverted the `$in`: You're looking for "posts that do have 'some_tag' in their `tag` field", but the query `{ "some_tag": { $in: tags } }` looks for documents that have a **field** `some_tag` with one of the value given in `tags`.